# Difference between modulus (%) and floor division(//) in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, integer-division

Recently, I read a book on Numpy which mentions different types of ufuncs, where I was encountered with two different ufuncs, namely 'modulus', denoted by `%` symbol and 'floor division' `//`. Can someone explain the difference between them and why two operators are provided to do the the same thing (display reminder of division, according to me)? Please correct, if I am wrong.

Comment: What makes you think they do the same thing? One gives the ramainder, the other the quocient

Comment: Just try to use them both and you will see. `13 // 4 = 3` and `13 % 4 = 1`. There is 4 three times in 13, but if you divide 13 by 4 you will get a remainder of 1.

Comment: Test your hypothesis - start your Python, try both with a few numbers. For instance, `for i in range(10): print (i//3, i%3)`

Answer (score 3):

Both are valid mathematical functions with different results.

**modulus**

The modulus-function computes the remainder of a division, which is the "leftover" of an integral division.

**floor**

The floor-function provides the lower-bound of an integral division. The upper-bound is computed by the ceil function. (Basically speaking, the floor-function cuts off all decimals).

```py
a=5
b=2
print(a%b) # Prints 1 as leftover
print(a//b) # Prints 2, since 5/2=2.5 and the decimal is cut off
print(a - (a//b)*b) # Prints 1, this is the modulo, calculated by the floor function
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume a= 10, b = 6

a%b will give you the remainder, that is 4

a//b will give you the quotient, that is 1

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between floor division and modulus may be helpful for understanding this:

```py
denominator = 6   # replace with any integer 
numerator   = 10  # replace with any integer 

floor_division_result = numerator//denominator 
modulo_result = numerator % denominator 

# this assertion will always be true: 
assert denominator * floor_division_result + modulo_result == numerator
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of the difference between modulus and floor division is to use an analogy of a clock face

[image]

Imagine a hand on this clock. It moves around and points at a number. Let's say a cycle starts (and ends) when the hand points at 12. In this context

- modulus, %, is where the hand is pointing right now
- floor division is the number of times the hand has completed a cycle

### Example 1

In the first cycle when the hand points at 4 the modulus is 4 but the floor division is 0.

```
4 % 12 # returns 4
4 // 12 # returns 0
```

### Example 2

In the second cycle when the hand points at 4 the modulus is still 4 but the floor division is now 1

```
16 % 12 # returns 4
16 // 12 # returns 1
```